# trying to get the word with starting upper case on first letter using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, uppercase

I have

```
              Visit table 
                 Visit_Id
                 Visit_Date values(09-09-2011)
                 Visit_status values like (accepted , refused)
                member_Id
```

i have done like this for getting number of visits 
by using below query

```
SELECT visit_Status as Status, COUNT('x') AS Visits
                              FROM visits
                              WHERE visit_Date BETWEEN '2011-06-20' AND '2011-07-20'
                              GROUP BY visit_Status
```

it was giving results like this

```
                Status          Visits
                accepted         2
                refused          4
```

can i get the results like this

```
                Status          Visits

                Accepted         2
                Refused          4


      with upper case letter on first letter of status i mean like this ( Accepted , Refused) instead of this one  (accepted , refused)
```

I am using mysql work bench

Answer (score 6, accepted):

u can use [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and  [UPPER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper)

```
select CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(visit_Status, 1, 1)), 
      LOWER(SUBSTRING(visit_Status FROM 2))) as Status ......
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(Visit_status, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(Visit_status FROM 2))) AS Status COUNT('x') AS Visits
       FROM visits
      WHERE visit_Date BETWEEN '2011-06-20' AND '2011-07-20'
      GROUP BY visit_Status
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(Visit_status, 1, 1)), SUBSTRING(Visit_status FROM 2)) as Status, COUNT('x') AS Visits
FROM visits
WHERE visit_Date BETWEEN '2011-06-20' AND '2011-07-20'
GROUP BY visit_Status
```